# Video Streaming using SSL on Alibaba ECS

Tags: php, ssl-certificate, video-streaming, lets-encrypt, alibaba-cloud-ecs

I have an ECS instance on Alibaba using LetsEncrypt for SSL configuration but i have an issue with PHP Video Streaming that is not working when SSL is used where Video Link gives 404 when the streaming begins but It works fine on http.

This is the used package for streaming: http://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial

And also this Package i already used and worked fine on another servers on https

Can anyone advice what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes users have the issue that all pages get 404 errors when SSL is activated. The cause may be differ from user to user and server to server. I have also faced this issue, try to do the following to get it resolved.

> 1) Re-save the permalinks, Re-saving makes sure the WordPress rewrite
>   rules get flushed. (If you are using WordPress)
>
> 2) If you have .htaccess files in your media directories, remove them, or adapt them to the https domain.
>
> 3) Check port bindings, sometimes binding may also cause this. i.e (There is no binding for https)